# How to add value in list from different children with Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Please help me, I was trying to get the data in `child("complaints")` and `child("complainee")`. The data gathered must be stored in List. List for child("complaints") and `list2` for `child("complainee")`. However, the `list2` was null when I display it. Thank you in advance.

[image: Here is my data structure in firebase]

```
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = database.getReference("complaints");

        list = new ArrayList<Blog>();
        list2 = new ArrayList<Complainee>();

        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                try{

                    for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 :dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                        final Blog value = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Blog.class);
                        Boolean Posted = value.getPosted();
                        String complaint_type = value.getComplaintType();

                        if(complaint_type.equals("Personal Complaint")) {

                            final int ComplaintNo = value.getComplaintNo();
                            String Description = value.getDescription();
                            String Date = value.getDate();
                            String MediaURL = value.getMediaURL();
                            String Time = value.getTime();
                            String Address = value.getAddress();

                            final Blog fire = new Blog();
                            fire.setComplaintNo(ComplaintNo);
                            fire.setDescription(Description);
                            fire.setDate(Date);
                            fire.setMediaURL(MediaURL);
                            fire.setTime(Time);
                            fire.setAddress(Address);
                            fire.setComplainee_Name(value.getComplainee_Name());



                           // Read from the database for COMPLAINEE
                           FirebaseDatabase database2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                            DatabaseReference myRef2 = database2.getReference("complainee").child(String.valueOf(ComplaintNo));

                            myRef2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnap) {

                                    Complainee cm = dataSnap.getValue(Complainee.class);

                                    String n = cm.getName();

                                    final Complainee fire2 = new Complainee();
                                    fire2.setName(n);
                                    fire2.setAddress("Address");
                                    list2.add(fire2);


                                }


                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }
                            });

                            list.add(fire);
                        }

                    }

                    Personal_RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter = new Personal_RecyclerAdapter(list,list2, getContext());
                    RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyce = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),1);
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyce);
                    recyclerView.setItemAnimator( new DefaultItemAnimator());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);


                }catch (Exception e){

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "::ERROR   " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Here is the Personal_RecyclerAdapter where I display the **list** and **list2**. The data in **list** was displayed perfectly but the data in **list2** displays nothing/null.

```
public class Personal_RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Personal_RecyclerAdapter.MyHoder>{



    List<Blog> list;
    List<Complainee> list2;


    Context context;

    public Personal_RecyclerAdapter(List<Blog> list, List<Complainee> list2 , Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.list2 = list2;


        this.context = context;
    }



    @Override
    public Personal_RecyclerAdapter.MyHoder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.individual_row_personalcomplaint,parent,false);
        Personal_RecyclerAdapter.MyHoder myHoder = new Personal_RecyclerAdapter.MyHoder(view);

        return myHoder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final Personal_RecyclerAdapter.MyHoder holder, final int position) {

        final Blog mylist = list.get(position);
        Complainee mylist2 = list2.get(position);



        holder.Description.setText(mylist.getDescription());
        holder.DateTime.setText(mylist.getDate() + " " + mylist.getTime());

        holder.Complainee.setText(mylist.getComplainee_Name());

        holder.Complainee.setText(mylist2.getName());
        holder.Complain_Address.setText(mylist.getAddress());


        holder.btn_inviteComplainant.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                Intent invitecomplainant = new Intent(context,brgy_inviteComplainant.class);
                invitecomplainant.putExtra("Personal_ComplaintNo", mylist.getComplaintNo());
                context.startActivity(invitecomplainant);
            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        int arr = 0;

        try{
            if(list.size()==0){

                arr = 0;

            }
            else{

                arr=list.size();
            }



        }catch (Exception e){



        }

        return arr;

    }

    class MyHoder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView Description,DateTime, Complain_Address,ComplaintNo, Complainee;
       // ImageView MediaURL;
        RelativeLayout relLyaout;
        Button btn_inviteComplainant;


        public MyHoder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            // ComplaintNo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_ComplaintNo);
            Description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.complain_description);
            DateTime= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.complain_datetime);
           // MediaURL= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageDisplay);

            Complainee = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.complain_complainee);
            Complain_Address = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.complain_address);
            btn_inviteComplainant = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_inviteComplainant);


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add a sample data structure in firebase??

Comment: here sir. https://i.stack.imgur.com/bU0ye.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to asynchronous nature of firebase listeners and you haven't notified your adapter of the changes. In your case you are adding the item to list `list.add(fire)` and then you have defined your recycler view. But you haven't waited for the list2's data to be added into the `list2.add(fire2)`.

Here is how your code should look like :

```
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = database.getReference("complaints");
    Personal_RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter = new Personal_RecyclerAdapter(list,list2, getContext());
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyce = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),1);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyce);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator( new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
    list = new ArrayList<Blog>();
    list2 = new ArrayList<Complainee>();

    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            try{

                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 :dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    final Blog value = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Blog.class);
                    Boolean Posted = value.getPosted();
                    String complaint_type = value.getComplaintType();

                    if(complaint_type.equals("Personal Complaint")) {

                        final int ComplaintNo = value.getComplaintNo();
                        String Description = value.getDescription();
                        String Date = value.getDate();
                        String MediaURL = value.getMediaURL();
                        String Time = value.getTime();
                        String Address = value.getAddress();

                        final Blog fire = new Blog();
                        fire.setComplaintNo(ComplaintNo);
                        fire.setDescription(Description);
                        fire.setDate(Date);
                        fire.setMediaURL(MediaURL);
                        fire.setTime(Time);
                        fire.setAddress(Address);
                        fire.setComplainee_Name(value.getComplainee_Name());



                       // Read from the database for COMPLAINEE
                        DatabaseReference myRef2 = database.getReference("complainee").child(String.valueOf(ComplaintNo));

                        myRef2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnap) {

                                Complainee cm = dataSnap.getValue(Complainee.class);

                                String n = cm.getName();

                                final Complainee fire2 = new Complainee();
                                fire2.setName(n);
                                fire2.setAddress("Address");
                                list2.add(fire2);
                                // Notify to your recyclerview that for the new data
                                recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            }


                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });

                        list.add(fire);
                        // Notify to your recyclerview that for the new data
                        recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }

                }




            }catch (Exception e){

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "::ERROR   " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

As soon as you get the data you have to notify the recyclerview adapter that some changes are there in the dataset.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Ok sir. Thank you

Comment: Why you are using two references while you can do it by one reference and using child?

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing database reference for child "complaints" by writing `myRef = database.getReference("complaints");`
and that's why getting null for "complainee" child.
Change your reference like-

`myRef = database.getReference();`

and then get value using

```
myRef.child("complainee").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ............
```

and for another

```
myRef.child("complaints").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ............
```

Hope your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is Query like this.!

```
     FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;

     DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;

     List<Complainee> complaineeList=new ArrayList();



        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference();

         mdatabaseRef.child("complainee").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override     
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

            if(complaineeList.size>0){
             complaineeList.clear();
             }

     Complainee complainee  =  childSnapshot.getValue(Complainee.class );

       complaineeList.add(complainee);




             }

     Adapter recyclerAdapter = new Adapter(complaineeList, getContext());

        }
```